# Printing columns of an equal custom set spacing while not letting long strings flow over other columns. (using clint perhaps?)

Tags: python, pretty-print, word-wrap, clint

Suppose I have these two lists:

```
column1 = ["Attribute:","Virtual machine:","Troll:"]
column2 = ["A value associated with an object which is referenced by name using dotted expressions. For example, if an object o has an attribute a it would be referenced as o.a.", 
           "A computer defined entirely in software. Python's virtual machine executes the bytecode emitted by the bytecode compiler.",
           "Someone who posts inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online community, such as a forum, chat room, or blog, with the primary intent of provoking readers into an emotional response or of otherwise disrupting normal on-topic discussion."]
```

This code:

```
for c1, c2 in zip(column1, column2):
    print "%-16s %s" % (c1, c2)
```

Ouputs this text:

```
Attribute:       A value associated with an object which is referenced by name u
sing dotted expressions. For example, if an object o has an attribute a it would
be referenced as o.a.
Virtual machine: A computer defined entirely in software. Python's virtual machi
ne executes the bytecode emitted by the bytecode compiler.
Troll:           Someone who posts inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messag
es in an online community, such as a forum, chat room, or blog, with the primary
 intent of provoking readers into an emotional response or of otherwise disrupti
ng normal on-topic discussion.
```

While I would like this:

```
Attribute:       A value associated with an object which is referenced by name 
                 using dotted expressions. For example, if an object o has an 
                 attribute a it would be referenced as o.a.
Virtual machine: A computer defined entirely in software. Python's virtual 
                 machine executes the bytecode emitted by the bytecode compiler.
Troll:           Someone who posts inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic 
                 messages in an online community, such as a forum, chat room, or 
                 blog, with the primary intent of provoking readers into an 
                 emotional response or of otherwise disrupting normal on-topic
                 discussion.
```

How do I get this result for any terminal size? (Someone advised me that [Clint](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint) might be able to achieve this quite easily, has anyone done this yet?)

Note: The requirement that a word is not chopped in pieces by the end of a line is only secondary for me. The most important requirement is letting each string element of the `column2` list continue with the same horizontal spacing as where the string of each element in that list started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from clint.textui import puts, columns

width = 20

for term, definition in zip(column1, column2):
    puts(columns([term, width], [definition, None]))
```

...prefix with this to choose column width based on content:

```
#derive 1st column width from longest term
width = 0
for s in column1:
    if len(s) > width :
        width = len(s) + 1
```

Adapted from [clint\examples\text_width.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint/blob/develop/examples/text_width.py). Thanks for the question; I didn't know how to do this before, and it's something I'll use.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import textwrap

for c1, c2 in zip(column1, column2):
    mc2 = "".join(textwrap.fill(c2, width=50, initial_indent="", subsequent_indent="\t\t ", break_long_words = False))
    print "%-16s %s" % (c1, mc2)
```

Whoever gets the same result with `Clint` gets the vote instead of this answer.